# How can I create a php web service, using POST, using JSON for sending req/res?

Tags: php, jquery, json, api

I am requested to create a web service, which uses POST instead of GET and so there should be no query string.  When a POST request is sent to /myservice a single JSON object will be passed with an attribute called "numbers."
       I'm thinking that this specification calls for a form which has just two fields, one a text field to hold the numbers, separated by commas, and a submit button field.
1) Should I use JavaScript and/or JQuery to get the numbers out of the form field and convert them into a JSON object?
       Specifically, the person enters into the form field, with name/id of "numbers," the numbers: 2, 3, 4. This needs to be turned into something like this:

```
{
  "numbers": [
     2, 3, 4
   ]
 }
```

Then I guess I would or could use JQuery's ajax methods to send the JSON data string to the 
php web service that exists at:
http://mydomain.com/myservice
It needs to be sent with no query parameters, as mentioned.  The service would return a json object representing the sum of all the numbers, the product of all the numbers, and the average or mean.  So, the result sent back would be

```
{
    "results": {
        "sum": 9,
        "product": 24,
        "average": 3
     }
}
```

Where I am getting stuck is probably in the area that is easiest.  I can have the form post to the same page and then can I have JQuery check to see if the form was posted, and if so then convert the numbers, entered into the form, into a JSON object.  Does JavaScript have access to the $_POST variable?
Or should I use an event handler to respond to a click on the form submit button.  But how do I get the data entered by the user and convert that into a JSON object with a parameter of "numbers?"

Then on the server side, I need to parse the JSON object, perform the operations on the array of numbers, and then create the JSON result object to be returned.
Can someone offer some advice, please?  I don't know if I should do the whole thing in PHP or if it is better to do some client-side JQuery/JavaScript processing to create the JSON object.
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0):

Look into [PHP's json_encode function](https://www.php.net/json_encode). If your numbers are posted in one field, you'll want to split them up by the delimiter to form an array, like this:

```
// custom callback function will trim the whitespace
// then convert to an integer
function trimAndConvert($string_number) {
    return (int)trim($string_number);
}

$numbers = explode(',', $_POST['your_numbers']); // get your input from $_POST
$numbers = array_map('trimAndConvert', $numbers); // trim whitespace and convert to int
$numbers = array('numbers' => $numbers);    

$json = json_encode($numbers);
```

Use [array_map](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to point to a custom callback function which will trim the whitespace off your exploded bits (they could be have spaces on either side etc) then convert to an integer. If you don't convert to integer, the numbers come out in JSON as strings (wrapped in quotes).

This will give you your desired JSON output, e.g.:

```
{
  "numbers": [2, 3, 4]
 }
```

From here, you can perform a POST request to that URL using CURL, or one of a couple of other options that don't use CURL (if you don't have it installed). See these articles:

- http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/
- http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php

Hope this helps.